# Is it ok to place link elements outside document's head section?

Tags: html, css

It's stated that the link element must be embedded in the head section.

I need to link some style sheets to a document with static predefined header (rendered by legacy framework). So I can't insert the tags to the head. Can placing them outside cause issues with any browsers ? Or maybe its better to insert the tags with javascript ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No version of HTML allows it, but browsers perform a great deal of error recovery. I wouldn't depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it especially on a website as opposed to a intranet. You will start to limit what browsers can view your site correctly. Please could you elaborate on your usage, I bet there is a better solution to the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: It's a simple framework (perl) using TT and predefined header template.